# ガスレンジ and 電子レンジ

Tags: loanwords

Does 電子レンジ not carry a meaning for electric stove as well as microwave?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33598/7810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

電子レンジ **only** refers to a microwave, that box-like device:

[image: 電子レンジ]

An electric stove like [this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/cooking-on-the-mini-electric-stove-top/70444521) is called 電気コンロ or 電熱線コンロ in Japanese. Although they are common in western countries, they are rare in Japan, and many people have not seen one. I suppose there are many people who imagine ["IH" (電磁調理器)](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/ih/59689867) instead when they hear 電気コンロ today. IHs are common in smaller apartments in Japan.

The most common type of cooking stove in Japan is ガスコンロ, which looks like [this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD/78674070) and is usually simply called コンロ. Laypeople do not usually say ガスレンジ, but you can read its meaning as jargon here: [What is the difference between ガスコンロ and ガスレンジ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33598/5010)

**EDIT:** Confusingly, in Japanese, ストーブ normally refers to a device to heat a room. A 電気ストーブ is an electric heater like [this](https://stock.adobe.com/jp/images/%E9%9B%BB%E6%B0%97%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96/106274152).

Answer (score 0):

電子ランジ is used exclusively for microwave oven (specifically for the microwave mode as some have multiple functions). For kitchen stoves there is ストーブ for [stove](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stove) or 電気焜炉{でんきこんろ} for [electric stove](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooktop#Electric) (also called a “cooktop” or “range” in English).

Specifying the source of energy gas or electric may seem redundant but it’s common in Japanese. 電車 for “electric train” for example, even though 汽車 steam trains are now rarely used. Similarly 電話 for telephone and 電信 for telegram.

Note that in Japanese households, most people cook with gas stoves ガスランジ or [“oven toasters”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toaster#Toaster_ovens) [オーブントースター](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC). Most people live in small apartments and city gas utilise are widely available. Electric stoves are so rare that ambiguity or confusion in Japan is unlikely.

Comment: `For electric stoves there is ストーブ` -- Naw.. [electric stove は調理器具](https://www.google.com/search?q=electric+stove&rlz=1C1CHZL_enJP778JP778&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3x-HwpbHqAhUAyosBHarMB_gQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1242&bih=577)ですが[日本語のストーブは暖房器具](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96&rlz=1C1CHZL_enJP778JP778&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOx_r4pbHqAhWiF6YKHUTrAv4Q_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1242&bih=577)です。日本では電気コンロとストーブは別物です。 `電子ランジ` `ガスランジ` <- 電子**レ**ンジ、ガス**レ**ンジ (or more commonly ガスコンロ)です。× **ラ**ンジ →◎ **レ**ンジ

Comment: Use of “range” and “stove” differs between US and UK/Australia English which may also cause confusion. Because of this the original question is ambiguous which is the correct translation in Japanese.

Comment: Ambiguous? You think OP may be asking whether 電子レンジ can refer to 暖房器具/ストーブ/heater, rather than whether 電子レンジ can refer to cooking hob/コンロ?　You aware that ストーブ in Japanese is a room heater, and not a cooking device?